# How to save/overwrite an annotated file with Evince?

Tags: evince, annotation

I am using the pre-installed Document Viewer (Evince) to annotate pdf-files. There does not seem to be a "Save" option and under "Save a Copy" I need to click through the folder to find the pdf location manually because the saving location is not the original pdf location by default. ("Open containing folder" opens the correct folder, but under "Save a Copy" the default is Desktop.)

I have the feeling there should be an easier work-flow. Do you have an idea?

Comment: Same problem. Would accept suggestions for an equally lightweight pdf viewer with simple annotate functionality that allows easy overwrite

Comment: related [issue](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/-/issues/1281) on gitlab -- no update :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use recent version of Evince, no need for workaround.

> I need to click through the folder to find the pdf location manually because the saving location is not the original pdf location by default.

The said issue is apparent for Evince 3.10.3 in 14.04 release. In my case, the default path is `$HOME/Downloads` rather than `$HOME/Desktop`. Not sure why the difference.

With recent version of Evince, the said issue is non-existent. I have at least confirmed that saving location is same as the original PDF location by default, using Evince 3.18.2 in 16.04 release.

> I have the feeling there should be an easier work-flow. Do you have an idea?

Sure. If you are consistently working from particular directory, consider to add that directory to the **Bookmarks** in File Manager. This way, you can always select the directory from the sidebar in File Chooser Dialog. This will reduce to just one or two clicks. Good enough?

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. Install `dconf-editor`, then launch it
2. Search for "evince".
3. In the `document`-directory, set 'Custom value' to **nothing**.
4. Apply the changes.
5. After that, if you want, you can press "Use default value" button.

[image: Changing evince save a copy dialog using dconf-editor]