# Save instead of Save as a copy in Evince Reader

Tags: 20.04, gnome, pdf, evince

I am currently using Evince Document Viewer Version 3.36.10 on Ubuntu 20.04. When I try to save an annotated pdf, it shows only the ***Save a copy*** option. How do I make it overwrite the current file? I have read a few similar questions on this platform but couldn't find any answers. So, is there any way to do it?

[Issue on GitLab](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/-/issues/1281)

[How to save/overwrite an annotated file with Evince?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/887437/how-to-save-overwrite-an-annotated-file-with-evince)

Answer (score 1):

It is how it works. You, however, can hit "Enter", and it will overwrite (update) your current file . I also do not understand the rationale to just have a "Save" command that does not prompt when a user wants to save annotations to the currently open PDF file.

This has been filed in issue [1281](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/-/issues/1281) and others. In an [earlier issue](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/-/issues/956), a developper indicated: "It works as intended, as Evince cannot guarantee loss of some PDF features currently unsupported by Poppler, the library used to render PDF.". As such, Gnome developpers prefer *never* to silently overwrite a PDF: overwriting it may discard/break features in the PDF that are not supported by the library.

Answer (score 0):

PDF is a complicated format and application that generate PDFs are not always fully compatible. I have seen PDF files that display properly in some PDF viewers, but not in others (what's interesting, I have seen files that **don't open correctly in Adobe Reader** (!) but for example Foxit Reader displays them OK). I have seen PDF files that are displayed correctly, but are messed up in print; but when you print them again to PDF, the resulting new PDF is printed OK. There can be various issues.

Therefore, when modifying a PDF file, I would personally never overwrite the original file until I verify that the saved modified version works correctly. Maybe that's the reason behind having "Save a copy" instead of overwriting the original file. Note that Adobe Reader also has "Save a copy" and not just "Save".